# How pass ArrayList data through intent() in gridView.setOnItemClickListener()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to know how pass ArrayList data through intent() in gridView.setOnItemClickListener() and get it in ShowTracksActivity.java. How is possible ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
ArrayList<Artist>artists = new ArrayList<Artist>();

// Artist 1
String[] artist_title = new String[]{ "Title 1", "Title 2","Title 3", "Title 4" };
artists.add(new Artist("Artist Name", "Album Name", "img_album", artist_title ));

// Artist 2
//...

ArtistAdapter adapter = new ArtistAdapter(this, artists);

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
  {

    Intent ShowTrackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTracksActivity.class);

    // Here ?
    // ShowTrackIntent.putExtra( ??? );

    startActivity(ShowTrackIntent);
  }
});
```

**ShowTracksActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ???
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to pass ArrayList as data or selected item of ArrayList?

Comment: Hi @AseemSharma, I display an artists list and when I click on one of them I want to pass data of this artist to ShowTracksActivity.java

Comment: Ok let me compose an answer for this as comment would be too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the idea, when you click on the artist you get position of that cell inside your click listener, so now you have to use that position and take out the artist from your artists list of that position. And pass it through intent, in android for passing user defined data/object you need to either make them Serializable or Parcelable.
You can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2736389/4878972)

Also Intent/Bundle class has methods for this type of data passing between Activities.

**Sample code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, value); // Here key would be String and value can be    either Parcelable or Serializable
startActivity(intent);
```

**In your case inside your item click listener:**

```
Artist artist = artists.get(postion);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTracksActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selected_artist", artist); // Here key would be String and value can be either Parcelable or Serializable
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:** You have to make your Artist class serializable for passing it to other activity, for how to do that you can refer this 
[Why use parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179861/4878972), [How To make class parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6923794/4878972) and [The easy and dirty way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827593/4878972)

Comment: It seems to be the good way, I had made a few adjustments but putExtra( ) show this error : Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, com.example.android.app.Artist)'

Comment: Have you made your Artist Model class Serializable or Parcelable ?

Comment: I used Parcelable has explain here [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html], but now I have this error on **new Artist** in `artists.add(new Artist(...));` : `'Artist(android.os.Parcel)' has private access in 'com.example.android.app.Artist'`

Comment: In fact it break my ArtistAdapter class, I'm from PHP and there are some logic that I do not understand yet... :-/

Comment: For making your artist class parcelable, you don't need to do it manually, Android Studio has plugin for that, you can generate parcelable class by it, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ok, so I changed my Artist.class by : `public class Artist extends ArrayList<Parcelable>{...}`
In `MainActivity.class : intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra ("key", artist);`
But in ShowTracksActivity.class : `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");` **<- Return []**.
And `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key").get(0);` **<- Return error**

Comment: You do not need to extend Artist with ArrayList<Parcelable>, let me share you a gist with proper implementation

Comment: Checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/devAseemSharma/aaa321d17e8171352aec7dd52538a8b8) and do the changes as per the need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in **MainActivity.java**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
  {
    Intent ShowTrackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTracksActivity.class);
    ShowTrackIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
    startActivity(ShowTrackIntent );
   }
});
```

And Retrieve it in **ShowTracksActivity.java**

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

I made something like that in order to pass a full object what ever it is using Gson

```
Intent ShowTrackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowTracksActivity.class);
ShowTrackIntent .putExtra("ObjectValue",new Gson().toJson(yourObject));
startActivity(ShowTrackIntent);
```

in the second activity when you pull the object you just need to pull it like the following

```
MyClassModel myModel=new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("ObjectValue"),MyClassModel.class);
```

You need to import the Powerfull [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) Library dependency, almost it is there in all projects

Answer (score 0):

You try:

**In MainActivity:**

`intent.putExtra("list", artists);`

**In ShowTracksActivity:**

```
ArrayList<Artist> list = (ArrayList<String>) 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

And `Artist` must is implements `Serializable`